# Qt - How things work together?

Tags: c++, qt

Below, I will show different files of an application from the `C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4` book, and have some questions on them.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "gotocelldialog.h"
//#include <QDialog>
//#include "ui_gotocelldialog.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);
//Ui::GoToCellDialog ui;
//QDialog *dialog = new QDialog;
GoToCellDialog *dialog = new GoToCellDialog;
//ui.setupUi(dialog);
dialog->show();
return app.exec();
}
```

**gotocelldialog.h**

```
#ifndef GOTOCELLDIALOG_H //Check if GOTOCELLDIALOG_H has not been defined previously
#define GOTOCELLDIALOG_H
#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_gotocelldialog.h"
class GoToCellDialog: public QDialog, public Ui::GoToCellDialog
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
GoToCellDialog(QWidget *parent = 0); 
private slots:
void on_lineEdit_textChanged();
};
#endif
```

**gotocelldialog.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "gotocelldialog.h"
GoToCellDialog::GoToCellDialog(QWidget *parent): QDialog(parent)
{
setupUi(this); //this: reference to the current class
QRegExp regExp("[A-Za-z][1-9][0-9]{0,2}");
QValidator *validator = new QRegExpValidator(regExp, this);
lineEdit->setValidator(validator);
connect(okButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(accept()));
connect(cancelButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(reject()));
}
void GoToCellDialog::on_lineEdit_textChanged()
{
okButton->setEnabled(lineEdit->hasAcceptableInput());
}
```

1- What is the use of putting `GoToCellDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);` in **gotocelldialog.h**, especially that it is allowing no parent to be passed?

2- In **main.cpp**, the commented code `ui.setupUi(dialog);` shows explicitly the `ui` I want to setup dialog to. But, in **gotocelldialog.cpp** you will see `setupUi(this);` without determining the `ui` I want to setup the current object to. How is it used here? And, what does setting up the user interface in this case mean?

3- In **gotocelldialog.cpp**, what does this line mean? `GoToCellDialog::GoToCellDialog(QWidget *parent): QDialog(parent)`. It is not clear for me how we are passing a parent here. How can we determine the parent from this line?

4- In **gotocelldialog.cpp**, is there another way of writing this line: `GoToCellDialog::GoToCellDialog(QWidget *parent): QDialog(parent)`? And, how can we write it if we remove the constructor Can it just begin with `GoToCellDialog {...}`?

Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: Following your previous questions on SO, I suggest you sit back and open a decent C++ book, then move forward to Qt.

Answer (score 1):

For 1): This is basic C++ syntax. It's a default argument. It makes it possible to call the constructor without passing in a pointer, in which case 0 (i.e. `NULL`) will be substituted.

For 2): please read the Qt documentation for UI files. That is explained there. (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-using-a-ui-file.html) (For what it means: please read the answers to your previous questions, the code generated by `uic` **and read the docs**).

For 3): again this is basic C++. It calls the superclass's constructor with `parent` as an argument.

For 4): no, you can't write C++ any which way you want. The syntax is strict, you have to follow it.

Please search the internet for C++ information and tutorials, there are hundreds of good references out there.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know how to answer your second question, but I'll try to answer others.

1) - if *parent* is 0, the new widget(gotocelldialog in our case) becomes a window. If *parent* widget is specified, then created widget becomes a child window inside the parent. Also child widget is deleted when its *parent* is deleted.

3) GoToCellDialog class is inhereted from QDialog class which has a constructor QDialog(QWidget *parent = 0). In this line you initialize base object with *parent*, which was passed to ctor of GoToCellDialog.

4) Yes you can jusr write something like this:

GoToCellDialog(QWidget *parent) {...}

But in this case you will miss the opportunity of making crteated GoToCellDialog object some other widget's child window on construction phase because QDialog base object will use default value for QWidget *parent parameter in it's ctor, which is 0 (see the item 1).